# Positioning a series labels across the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following function inside my React web app:

```
function DisplayInfo(props) {
    const flexStyle = {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 1,
        margin: 20,
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'center'
    };

    const labelStyle = {        
        zIndex: 1,
        margin: 20
    };

    return (      
        <div className="flex-container" style={flexStyle}>
            <label style={labelStyle}>
                Data1: {props.data}
            </label>
            <label style={labelStyle}>
                {props.moreInfo}
            </label>
            <label style={labelStyle}>
                {props.interestingMessage}
            </label>
        </div>  
    );
}
```

My target is to get a horizontal, evenly spaced list across the screen; however, what I have just puts everything in the top left of the screen.  I've tried `justifyContent: 'center'` but if makes no difference.

Please can someone put me on the right css path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `justifyContent` property to work, you first need to set to make it a flex container. Also, to have your items evenly spaced, instead of `space-between`, use the below:

```
const flexStyle = {
    display: 'flex',
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 1,
    margin: 20,
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    alignItems: 'center'
};
```

In addition to the above, I noticed that that the container is absolutely positioned. Adding a `width` of `100%` will do the trick for you.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference to the display at all

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to react, you need to specify the `width` of the `absolute` element.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; 
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center
}

.labelStyle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <label class="labelStyle">
                data
            </label>
  <label class="labelStyle">
                moreInfo
            </label>
  <label class="labelStyle">
                interestingMessage
            </label>
</div>
```